# Convert Horizontal text file to vertical CSV file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a text file which has each column as a row and a header to represent start of new record. I need to convert this to a vertical CSV using Python.

Not all columns apply to each records so I can set them up either blank or 0.

Please see example below:

```
WERF   this is vendor1 data
this is col1 : 20
this is col2 : 30
here is col1 scenario2: 1
here is col2 scenario2: 3
ADEF this is vendor2 data
this is col1 : 2
this is col2 : 3
TRGF this is vendor3 data
this is col1 : 10
this is col2 : 12
PSDFAA this is vendor4 data
this is col1 : 4
this is col2 : 7
here is col1 scenario2: 12
here is col2 scenario2: 11
```

Expected output:

```
Vendor    this is col1  this is col1   here is col1 scenario2  here is col2 scenario2
WERF      20            30              1                      3
ADEF      2             3
TRGF      10            12
PSDFAA    4             7               12                     11
```

Please suggest how to implement this in Python.

Comment: Is the second `vendor2` supposed to be `vendor3`?

Comment: fixed the typo now.

Comment: Do you really have irrelevant information on your rows like "Vendor1 this is vendor1 data" instead of "vendor1"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's a typo and the `Vendor3` should be in the input text.

You can use `re` module to parse the text and create a dataframe, eg.:

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

txt = """\
Vendor1 this is vendor1 data
this is col1 : 20
this is col2 : 30
here is col1 scenario2: 1
here is col2 scenario2: 3
Vendor2 this is vendor2 data
this is col1 : 2
this is col2 : 3
Vendor3 this is vendor3 data
this is col1 : 10
this is col2 : 12
Vendor4 this is vendor4 data
this is col1 : 4
this is col2 : 7
here is col1 scenario2: 12
here is col2 scenario2: 11"""


all_data = {}

for vendor, group in re.findall(
    r"^(\S[^\n]+?)\s+this is[^\n]+data$(.*?)(?=(?:^\S[^\n]+?\s+this is[^\n]+data$)|\Z)",
    txt,
    flags=re.S | re.M,
):
    all_data[vendor] = {}
    for k, v in re.findall(r"\s*(.*?)\s*:\s*(.*)", group):
        all_data[vendor][k] = v

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_data, orient="index")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        this is col1 this is col2 here is col1 scenario2 here is col2 scenario2
Vendor1           20           30                      1                      3
Vendor2            2            3                    NaN                    NaN
Vendor3           10           12                    NaN                    NaN
Vendor4            4            7                     12                     11
```

Comment: Can you please explain the regular expression used. I am not able to follow this.

Comment: @PythonDeveloper With first regex I find all groups (group is here from the line `VendorX this is vendorx data` to the next `VendorX this is vendorx data`, of course vendorx could be anything). With second regex I just find all key-values.  Here is link to regex101: https://regex101.com/r/aSxEGW/1

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which uses `groupby` to create a list of dataframes, one for each vendor. Then, the dataframes are conveniently manipulated and, finally, concatenated.

I am using @AndrejKesely's data, to whom I thank.

```
text = """
Vendor1 this is vendor1 data
this is col1 : 20
this is col2 : 30
here is col1 scenario2: 1
here is col2 scenario2: 3
Vendor2 this is vendor2 data
this is col1 : 2
this is col2 : 3
Vendor3 this is vendor3 data
this is col1 : 10
this is col2 : 12
Vendor4 this is vendor4 data
this is col1 : 4
this is col2 : 7
here is col1 scenario2: 12
here is col2 scenario2: 11
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\t', header=None, names=['col'])

m = df['col'].str.startswith('Vendor')
g = df.groupby(m.cumsum(), sort=False)
dfs = [x.iloc[1:,0].str.split('\s*: ', expand=True) for _, x in g]
out = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(x[0], x[1])), index=range(1)) for x in dfs])
vendors = (df.loc[m, 'col']
           .str.extract('(Vendor\d)*')
           .set_axis(['Vendors'], axis=1))
pd.concat([vendors.reset_index(drop=True), out.reset_index(drop=True)],  axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Vendors this is col1 this is col2 here is col1 scenario2  \
0  Vendor1           20           30                      1   
1  Vendor2            2            3                    NaN   
2  Vendor3           10           12                    NaN   
3  Vendor4            4            7                     12   

  here is col2 scenario2  
0                      3  
1                    NaN  
2                    NaN  
3                     11
```

Comment: I just realized I do not have the group row starting with Vendor. I just updated my examples. Can you please take a look if possible.

Comment: Are the first words (that replace Vendors) *always* uppercase and the following words lowercase, @PythonDeveloper?

Answer (score 0):

Using @AndrejKesely's data, you do a bit of prepping before pivoting:

```py
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), header=None, names=['C'])

In [101]: df
Out[101]: 
                               C
0   Vendor1 this is vendor1 data
1              this is col1 : 20
2              this is col2 : 30
3      here is col1 scenario2: 1
4      here is col2 scenario2: 3
5   Vendor2 this is vendor2 data
6               this is col1 : 2
7               this is col2 : 3
8   Vendor3 this is vendor3 data
9              this is col1 : 10
10             this is col2 : 12
11  Vendor4 this is vendor4 data
12              this is col1 : 4
13              this is col2 : 7
14    here is col1 scenario2: 12
15    here is col2 scenario2: 11
```

```py
(df
.assign(out=df.C.mask(df.C.str.startswith('Vendor')), 
        C =  df.C.str.extract(r'(Vendor\d)').ffill())
.dropna()
.assign(out = lambda f: f.out.str.split(':'), 
        header = lambda f: f.out.str[0].str.strip(), 
        values = lambda f: f.out.str[-1].str.strip().astype(int))
.drop(columns='out')
.pivot(index='C', columns='header', values='values')
.fillna(0)
.rename_axis(index=None,columns=None)
)

         here is col1 scenario2  here is col2 scenario2  this is col1  this is col2
Vendor1                     1.0                     3.0          20.0          30.0
Vendor2                     0.0                     0.0           2.0           3.0
Vendor3                     0.0                     0.0          10.0          12.0
Vendor4                    12.0                    11.0           4.0           7.0
```

Comment: I just realized I do not have the group row starting with Vendor. I just updated my examples. Can you please take a look if possible.

Comment: kindly convert the input dataframe to a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_file(filename):
    with open('data.txt') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                yield line

data = {}
for line in read_file('data'):
    if not ':' in line:
        key = line.split()[0].strip()
        data[key] = {}
    else:
        k, v = line.split(':', maxsplit=1)
        data[key][k.strip()] = v.strip()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       this is col1 this is col2 here is col1 scenario2 here is col2 scenario2
WERF             20           30                      1                      3
ADEF              2            3                    NaN                    NaN
TRGF             10           12                    NaN                    NaN
PSDFAA            4            7                     12                     11
```